# Add minimum order field basd on Variable Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I want to ad custom minimum order field on woocommerce to set minimum order, but I have tried the code but it does not work on variable product.
Any help is appreciated.

My code so far:

```
function add_minimum_order_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => 'minimum_order',
            'class' => 'wc_input_price short',
            'label' => 'minimum order',
            'desc_tip' => true,
            'description' => 'set the minimum order',
        )
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_minimum_order_field');

function save_minimum_order_field($post_id) {
    $minimum_order = isset($_POST['minimum_order']) ? wc_clean($_POST['minimum_order']) : '';
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'minimum_order', $minimum_order);
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_minimum_order_field');

function validate_minimum_order($passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    $minimum_order = get_post_meta($product_id, 'minimum_order', true);

    if ($quantity < $minimum_order) {
        wc_add_notice(sprintf('The minimum order must be %s.', $minimum_order), 'error');
        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validate_minimum_order', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some problems based on variable product. So you should consider variable product function, if you want to have the minimum order field on variable product section. So, I have revisited your code nearly completely and managed to fix your issues.

```
/*Minimum Order - Simple & Variable Product*/
// Add minimum order field to product options
function add_minimum_order_field() {
    global $product_object;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => 'minimum_order',
            'class' => 'wc_input_price short',
            'label' => 'Minimum Order',
            'desc_tip' => true,
            'description' => 'Set the minimum order for this product',
            'value' => get_post_meta($product_object->get_id(), 'minimum_order', true), // Populate the field with the saved value
        )
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_minimum_order_field');

// Save minimum order field value
function save_minimum_order_field($product) {
    $minimum_order = isset($_POST['minimum_order']) ? wc_clean($_POST['minimum_order']) : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('minimum_order', $minimum_order);
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_minimum_order_field');

// Add minimum order field to product variations
function add_minimum_order_field_to_variations($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => 'minimum_order[' . $variation->ID . ']',
            'class' => 'wc_input_price short',
            'label' => 'Minimum Order',
            'desc_tip' => true,
            'description' => 'Set the minimum order for this variation',
            'value' => get_post_meta($variation->ID, 'minimum_order', true), // Populate the field with the saved value
        )
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'add_minimum_order_field_to_variations', 10, 3);

// Save minimum order field value for product variations
function save_minimum_order_field_for_variations($variation_id, $i) {
    $minimum_order = isset($_POST['minimum_order'][$variation_id]) ? wc_clean($_POST['minimum_order'][$variation_id]) : '';
    update_post_meta($variation_id, 'minimum_order', $minimum_order);
}
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_minimum_order_field_for_variations', 10, 2);

// Validate minimum order on add to cart
function validate_minimum_order($passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    $minimum_order = get_post_meta($product_id, 'minimum_order', true);

    if ($quantity < $minimum_order) {
        wc_add_notice(sprintf('The minimum order should be %s.', $minimum_order), 'error');
        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validate_minimum_order', 10, 3);
```